# How to horizontally center the buttons in a fixed sized div?

Tags: html, css

Below is the code, two buttons in one div.

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 300px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid;">
<input type="button" value="ok" style="position:relative; width: 70px; height: 30px;">
<input type="button" value="ok" style="position:relative; width: 70px; height: 30px;">
</div>
```

How to horizontally center the buttons in fixed sized did ?

Comment: could you explain a bit more ? How should the button appear

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Adding `text-align:center;` CSS to the `<div>` will center the buttons. You should also consider separating the *style* from the *content*, which [amongst other reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content), reduces the duplication. For example

#### CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid;
    text-align:center;
}

input {
    position:relative;
    width:70px;
    height:30px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="ok"/>
    <input type="button" value="ok"/>
</div>
```

**Edit:** The [official definition for `text-align`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-align) states:

> The text-align property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned

so it will centre *all* inline level elements and [`<input>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) is an inline element.

Comment: +1 for making me understand a new thing , but how does it exactly work.Till now I thought it can be used only with the text inside the div

Comment: I have edited my answer with the reason why `text-align:center` works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 300px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid; text-align:center;">
<input type="button" value="ok" style="position:relative; width: 70px; height: 30px;">
<input type="button" value="ok" style="position:relative; width: 70px; height: 30px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **text-align:center;** to your main div & don't need to use inline css we should define css classes through external **CSS** files and here we don't need any kind of positioning we can do easily by simple **CSS**

```
**CSS**

  div {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 30px; 
  border: 1px solid; 
  text-align:center;
  }
  .button {
   width: 70px; 
   height: 30px;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="ok" class="button">
<input type="button" value="ok" class="button">
</div>
```

demo :- http://jsbin.com/evomik/10/edit

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 300px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid;">
<div id="button_container" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<input type="button" value="ok" style="position:relative; width: 70px; height: 30px;">
<input type="button" value="ok" style="position:relative; width: 70px; height: 30px;">
</div>
</div>
```